# how to design const member function, preventing it from modifying the object

Tags: c++

This a const member function, which allow me to get the minimum node of the tree:

```
BinarySearthTree* BinarySearchTree::min() const                                        
{                                                                                      
    // Return the minimum node (left-most node) value of the tree                      
    BinarySearchTree * next = (BinarySearchTree *) this;                               

    for (next ; next != NULL; next = next->pLeft)                                      
        if (next->pLeft == NULL)                                                       
            return next;                                                               
}
```

I have to cast down the const-ness of 'this' pointer when assigning it to 'next', but this actually rises the potential that I may modify the value of what 'this' points to? Rather than always remind myself not to modify whatever 'next' points to, is there a way to prevent it happening by a better designing of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `next` `const`:

```
const BinarySearthTree* BinarySearchTree::min() const                                        
{                                                                                      
    // Return the minimum node (left-most node) value of the tree                      
    const BinarySearchTree *next;                               

    for (next = this; next != NULL; next = next->pLeft)                                      
        if (next->pLeft == NULL)                                                       
            return next;
    return NULL;                                                               
}
```

Comment: I make the method const because I want it to work both on const and non-const object, and I want the result from a const object not modifiable and the result from a non-const object  modifiable. If I declare the function return type also 'const', then it doesn't work on the case of non-const object. Or I should have two function separately?

Comment: Yes you can either provide 2 versions; one const and the other non-const, or just stick with a single non-const version (this would be my preference).

Comment: It's a common pattern to just provide the `const` version and the `non-const` version simply does a const_cast `const_cast` on the call and return from the `non-const` version.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the contents to be modified, then you should make `min()` return a pointer to a `const` object.

Your `next` variable should also be a pointer to a `const` object, therefore.

Here is how I think your method should look:

```
const BinarySearchTree* BinarySearchTree::min() const
{
    // Return the minimum node (left-most node) value of the tree
    for (const BinarySearchTree* next = this; next != NULL; next = next->pLeft)
    {
        if (next->pLeft == NULL)
        {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Also, in C++, you should avoid C-style casts. The `const_cast` exists for this purpose:

```
BinarySearchTree* next = const_cast<BinarySearchTree*>(this);
```

But that is not necessary in this instance.